# How do you turn a column of data from SQL into a list in python?

Tags: python, sql, list

I am getting [[90], [99], [95], [92], [93]]
but I want [90, 99, 95, 92, 93] so I can use the list.

Here is the code I used:

```
c.execute("SELECT (mark) FROM class")
            result = c.fetchall()
            count= 0
            a = []
            for i in result:
                    count += 1
                    a.append(list(i))

            print(count)
            print(a)
```

Comment: It'd help if you included what driver you're using as well.

Comment: your loop is not required. `c.fetchall()` will return a list itself. You are just iterating over the resultset to count which might not be required?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
a.append(list(i))
```

with

```
a.append(i)
```

The extra call to `list` is wrapping each element in its own list.

Depending on what kind of object `result` is, you might be able to do simply

```
a = list(result)
```

instead of your for loop

**Update**

Looks like you need to do (in for loop):

```
a.append(i[0])
```

or (without for loop):

```
a = [x[0] for x in result]
```

Comment: with a.append(i) i still get [(90,), (99,), (95,), (92,), (93,)]. 'result' is a group of integers. My aim is to try and edit the list in various ways.

Comment: @NahilaChowdhury: Read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)